# Custom lightning component's text area content not available during initial page load in controller's javascript

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I created a custom lightning component that has a text area(**plain HTML and not lightning/UI component for a reason. Refer to comments sections if you need to know why**) and a submit button. Ignoring unwanted complexities, the functionality is for the submit button to save the text area content in a backend table on click of the button. The lightning component is on a custom lightning page.

Problem:
When the lightning page loads for the first time and the Submit button is clicked with some data in the text area, the javascript controller gets the content of the text area as empty. However, when I refresh the page and enter some data in the text area, the submit button captures the text as expected.

My understanding:
I believe the text area is probably not available in the DOM yet during the first load. I found this by placing breakpoint in the JS code using chrome dev tools. On first load the jquery selector on the text area(I have highlighted this line of code with //***) returned empty string though the text area had value. On refreshing the page I got back the value as expected. This is a basic use case and I believe there should be a simpler answer to my problem which I am not able to figure out. Any help is much appreciated!

Here is my code;

Component Code(Removed some irrelevant code here):

```
<aura:component controller="MeetingNotesApexController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

<ltng:require styles="{!join(',', $Resource.At_Css)}"  
                scripts="{!join(',', $Resource.jquery, $Resource.Caret_Js, $Resource.At_Js)}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}" />

    <aura:attribute name="commentText" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="submitBtnLabel" type="String" default="Submit Comment"/>


    <div style="margin-top: 0.25cm; margin-bottom: 0.50cm">
        <textarea id="commentsTextArea" style="margin-bottom: 0.25cm" required = "true" value="{!v.commentText}" class="slds-textarea" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Enter your comments" onkeyup = "{!c.displayTypeAheadMenu}"></textarea>
        <lightning:button variant="brand" aura:id="commentEditorSubmitBtn" label="{!v.submitBtnLabel}" title="" onclick="{!c.handleSaveMeetingComment}" />
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isUpdate}">
            <lightning:button variant="brand" aura:id="commentEditorCancelBtn" label="Cancel" title="" onclick="{!c.handleCancelEditBtn}" />
        </aura:if>
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

Controller code(Just the method that handles Save):

```
({
handleSaveMeetingComment: function(component, event, helper){
    var isUpdate = component.get('v.isUpdate');
    //*********************************************************************
    var textAreaValue = jQuery('#commentsTextArea').val();
    //*********************************************************************
    var meetingCommentListComp = component.find("meetingCommentsComp");
    var meetingProductFamiliesComp = component.find("meetingProductFamiliesComp");
        var meetingRecord = component.get("v.meetingRecord");
        console.log("Meeting Record in Esle = " + meetingRecord);
        var meetingDetailsId = meetingRecord.MeetingDetails__c;
        console.log("Meeting details Id = " + meetingDetailsId);
        component.set("v.simpleNewMeetingComment.Comment_Text__c", textAreaValue);
        component.set("v.simpleNewMeetingComment.Meeting_Id__c", component.get("v.recordId"));
        component.set("v.simpleNewMeetingComment.MeetingDetails__c", meetingDetailsId);

component.find("meetingCommentRecordCreator").saveRecord(function(saveResult){
            if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
                    // record is saved successfully
                    var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                    resultsToast.setParams({
                        "title": "Save Complete",
                        "message": "Comment saved!"
                    });
                    resultsToast.fire();
                    //Clear text area contents
                    jQuery('#commentsTextArea').val('')
                    //reloads the view
                    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
                    //creates new template for LDS component, or it overwrites the previous save.
                    helper.createTemplateForMeetingRecordCreator(component);
                    meetingCommentListComp.doInit();
                    meetingProductFamiliesComp.doInit();
                    console.log('Save successful');

                } else if (saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                    // handle the incomplete state
                    console.log("User is offline, device doesn't support drafts.");
                } else if (saveResult.state === "ERROR") {
                    // handle the error state
                    console.log('Problem saving comment, error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult));
                } else {
                    console.log('Unknown problem, state: ' + saveResult.state + ', error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
                }
        });
    }
})
```

If I have missed any information that is needed for figure out the issue, please let me know and I will provide them.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're using jQuery` to read textarea` value? Ideally, you should be reading the `v.commentText` attribute to read the value in controller function and using `ui:inputTextArea` standard framework Component.

Comment: @VarunC, I am having an external JS library that adds events to the text area for auto-complete. If I use ui:inputTextArea I am not able to add these custom events to the text area.

This is the custom event;
jQuery("#commentsTextArea").atwho({ .....
        });

I get an error stating unknown function called "atwho" if I use ui:inputTextArea. This is what I tried;
1.) Get the ui:inputTextArea by aura:id
2.) From the result of above statement I called the .atwho method.

If there is something I missed in the ui:inputTextArea approach, please let me know.

Comment: @VarunC, If I directly use the v.commentText instead of the jQuery selector, the save might work(haven't tested this), however, the auto-complete on the text area wouldn't which is a requirement for me, unfortunately. 

P.S. Continuing my prev comment here since there is a word count limit per comment.

Comment: There may be some issues with how the autocomplete works. The DOM is not fully built when a component is initialized and may or may not be fully built when your scripts load. Without knowing the details of the third party libraries, it is tough to say for sure that this is causing the problem. However, can you try debugging the value of your textarea (as returned by jQuery) in the `afterRender`? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm

Comment: Yes using `afterRender` should be helpful for you in that case. I'm pasting few lines of code so moving that bit of code into an answer below, since can't paste the code properly in comments here.

Comment: @dsharrison I did try afterRender before posting the question and the autocomplete did work. However, calling the doInit() in the afterRender event makes the doInit() method go on an infinite loop for some reason. Probably, figuring out why it goes on an infinite loop and fixing that might be the answer. The reason I posted the question here is that I feel like this is a common use case and there should be a simpler answer that I might be missing. Thanks for the insight though!

Comment: Related:? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/192106/3996

Comment: @Eric, looks like my scenario is different.

Comment: @VarunC, Using v.commentText returns undefined even when jQuery selector gives back value. Looks like using v.commentText directly is not an option. I am going to try playing around with the afterRender. Will let know how that turns out.

Answer (score 0):

Using an `afterRender` along with a custom poll function that will retry calling your code until your JS libraries have been loaded properly. Sometimes 3rd party libraries take some time injecting into framework.

```
({
    afterRender: function(component, helper) {
        /* globals $ */

        var timesToCheck = 20;
        var poll = function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('timesToCheck: '+timesToCheck);
                timesToCheck -= 1;
                if (typeof $ !== 'undefined' && component.isValid()) {
                    //perform your custom intialization code for auto complete textarea hook here

                } else if (timesToCheck > 0) {
                    poll();
                } else {
                    console.log('giving up')
                }
            }, 500);
        };

        poll();

    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @VarunC, you can use the ReRenderer.

```
 "doInit" : function(cmp){
        cmp.set("v.isJqueryLoaded",true);// to check if scripts are loaded
        cmp.set("v.needToProcessReRenderLogic",true); // when to run the rerender
    }
```

```
rerender : function(cmp, helper){
        this.superRerender();

        if(cmp.get("v.isJqueryLoaded") && cmp.get("v.needToProcessReRenderLogic")) {
            //your logics

            //Finally set the needToProcessReRenderLogic to false, since rerender will be called multiple times
            cmp.set("v.needToProcessReRenderLogic",false); // this will not fire rerender again
        }
    }
```